# CSS: div height take all available space of the parent

Tags: css

I have this:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

I want that content take all remaining space of the parent, but when I added height: 100% in css it takes exactly 100% of the parent height. How to set the height of the content div to height of the parent - height of the header?

Comment: You have a fixed height for #header ?

Comment: You can do height:inherit

Comment: yes the header has fixed height set to 30 px

Comment: [take a look at this](http://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/99J2u/) is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99J2u/), is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: @TechnoKnol, yes but flex is quite new and probably not supported in every browser.

Comment: @BartoszBialecki, yes then preshank's answer will suite your need, however you can check cross browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

Comment: @TechnoKnol, thanks, but unfortunately this is not supported in IE 9 and 8, which I need also.

Comment: okay, it does not matter what method you use. `calc` is also not supported in IE8 and partial support for IE9, [check here](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: You're right, so I can use flex, but there is maybe other solution which don't use these new features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, the height is 30px so you can try this

```
#content {
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

EDIT: http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/ some info for those who don't know about calc

Answer (score 2):

Option one, use `position: absolute` for header to pop it out:

```
#main{
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
}

#header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Option two, use css [`Calc()`](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/):

```
#content{
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

Option three, use jQuery:

```
$('#content').css({
   height: ($('#main').height() - $('#header').height()) + 'px';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`Display: flex` is the property what you are looking for.

take a look at this

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/99J2u/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="header">blah blah blah header </div>
    <div id="content"> content  content  content  content  content  content  content  cdfadfdasfafontent  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  cont fdsfasfadf adsf da fads fa fa ent <div> content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  contenfafda fa fs ff   content  content  content </div> content  content  contencontent content t content content content content content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
html, body {
    height:300px;
}
#main  {
    height:390px;
    background: #999; 
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#header {
    background: #555;
}
#content {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display:flex; 
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do  
so the height will be same as your text

Comment: the main div has fixed size, but the user can resize it, so the content should fill all height of the main div - height if the header.